# Azure PowerShell Runbook does not support System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-runbook

I am trying to open a connection with a ssas server and execute a dax query in order to extract table metadata, through a powershell runbook from an Azure Automation Account.

$daxConnectionString = "Provider=MSOLAP;Data Source=..."

I'm using the following code:

```
$daxConnectionString = "Provider=MSOLAP;Data Source=$daxServer;Initial Catalog=$daxCatalog;UID=$daxUserId;PWD=$daxPwd"
$daxConnection = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
$daxConnection.ConnectionString = $daxConnectionString
$daxConnection.Open() 
$daxCommand = $daxConnection.CreateCommand()
```

The system return the following exception:

```
System.Management.Automation.MethodInvocationException: Exception calling "Open" with "0" argument(s): "The .Net Framework Data Providers require Microsoft Data Access Components(MDAC).  Please install Microsoft Data Access Components(MDAC) version 2.6 or later." ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The .Net Framework Data Providers require Microsoft Data Access Components(MDAC).  Please install Microsoft Data Access Components(MDAC) version 2.6 or later. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {2206CDB2-19C1-11D1-89E0-00C04FD7A829} failed due to the following error: 800736b1 The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect. Please see the application event log or use the command-line sxstrace.exe tool for more detail. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800736B1).
```

Is there a MDAC module available or can I solve this in an other way?

Thanks in advance,
Bart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To connect to the Analysis server. I'm not using a connection based on the MSOLAP provider but based on the ADOMD Client

```
daxConnectionString = "Data Source=$daxServer;Initial Catalog=$daxCatalog;User ID=$daxUserId;Password=$daxPwd"
$daxConnection = New-Object Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.AdomdConnection
$daxConnection.ConnectionString = $daxConnectionString
$daxConnection.Open() 
$daxCommand = $daxConnection.CreateCommand()
```

With this in place the dataset can be filled like:

```
 $daxAdapter = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.AdomdDataAdapter $daxCommand
 $daxDataset = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.DataSet
 $daxCommand.CommandText = $query
 $nrRows = $daxAdapter.Fill($daxDataset)
```

The only thig is that the AdomdClient is not available in the RunBook and also not available in Modules... we create our own...

- Download the nuget package from : [Nuget.org](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.retail.amd64/)
- Rename the package extension to .zip
- Search inside the package for the DLL called Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient
- Copy the Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.dll file and paste it inside a new folder.
- Right-click on the folder and send it to zip.
- Add the zip file to the runbook modules by "Adding a module"

Be sure that in the RunBook the library get's loaded by:

```
$assemblyPath = "C:\Modules\User\Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient\Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.dll"
try {Add-Type -Path $assemblyPath}
catch  { $_.Exception.LoaderExceptions }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **OledbSql** PowerShell  [Module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/OledbSql/1.0.4) to add in an azure automation for connection.

I have added the module in Azure Runbook. Which follows:
[image]

#### Import Module from local

[image]

From Gallery
[image]

[image]

Importing the module
[image]

Comment: OledbSql module is installed,
Unfortunately I need the MSOLAP Provider to talk to the analysis Cube: DAX query.
Provider=MSOLAP
So this is not working